# Euler-Mascheroni constant as local minima of a function

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, gamma-function, constants, digamma-function

Let define the function $x>0$:

$$f(x)=\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)-x$$

Then $x_0$ such that :

$$f(x_0)=-\gamma$$

Define a local minima ([see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=extrema%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22GlobalExtremaCalculator%22%2C%20%22curvefunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%20Gamma%281%2Fx%29-x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22GlobalExtremaCalculator%22%2C%20%22domain%22%7D%20-%3E%220%3Cx%22)) of the function $f(x)$.(We have the Gamma function and the negative Euler-Mascheroni constant)

To prove it I have tried derivative we have $x>0$ :

$$f'(x)=-\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)\psi\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)}{x^2}-1$$

But we want :

$$f'(x)=0$$

Or :

$$\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)\psi\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=x^2$$

And now the best things I can do is to use Newton's method to check my result .

### Question

Is there an hidden closed form here ?

How to solve it ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The truth is that $f(x) >  - \gamma$ for all $x>0$ and $\lim _{x \to  + \infty } f(x) =  - \gamma$.

Comment: I graphed $f(x)$ and for $x>0$ it is monotonically decreasing. It has at 9 extrema for $-1<x<0$, tho...

Comment: @Gary it seems that Geogebra have some bugs sorry . For the rest it's implied by the power series of $\Gamma(x)$ I forgot it !